# Could a junkyard be provide a better-than-average basis for habitation after the apocalypse?

Tags: post-apocalypse, waste

So, some people go to an average sized junkyard, after a total nuclear war just ended. They decide to make the junkyard home, and even name it “Junk City”. Cut to a few centuries later and it becomes a religious holy site, like Mecca. But let’s focus on the now.

Could a junkyard be a good place to build a city after the apocalypse? What advantages and disadvantages would it have compared to rebuilding a traditional living area (like a city or suburb)?

Comment: Sorry as soon as I started writing an answer that began "yes and no" I realised that this is an "opinion based" question and they're a poor fit on this stack I'm afraid.

Comment: @Ash: Can you continue writing that answer?

Comment: The 'best' place to build any settlement is all about the basics: Reliable food, water, shelter, protection, waste disposal. Most cities grow from settlements based upon (mostly) economic criteria: Enough extra resources for a population to begin specializing and access to trade routes to trade those specialist-produced goods and services. While a junkyard would provide a lot of pre-refined metals, the rest of the basics still need to be there.

Comment: You could make this less opinion-based (subjective) and more objective by including a definition of a "good place".  Or defining a metric for goodness.  E.g. minimizing labor.

Comment: @Brythan: A place with resources and stuff to build with

Comment: I could but I really shouldn't not after I VTC'd the question. I was thinking about resource availability vs environmental suitability.

Comment: No junkyards are majority organic matter (like 90% paper i think) a few years after your people move in your junk yard will likely catch on fire and it will stay that way for a couple years. perhaps after such a fire has burned through all the available material it could then become a very rich mine

Comment: Why would building a city be a good thing to do after an apocalypse?  Surely the point of having an apocalypse in the first place is to get rid of the cities :-)  Seriously, your main concern post-apocalypse is going to be food, and junkyards are not good places for farms.  Maybe a small community lives in one, and trades with surrounding farms?

Comment: @Ummdustry: No, junkyards are mostly non-working cars and trucks.  You're perhaps thinking of a dump or landfill?

Comment: Consider what made you ask the question. Is a junkyard a significant setting for your story? How does it help the plot, help or hurt your characters? Do they need to live there or can it be nearby? As user 535733 said, the basics are first about food and water. Shelter can be even more important depending on the environment - you can survive a couple of days without food and water but you could freeze to death quickly without adequate shelter/protection from the elements. --- Once the basics are met, you can create whatever setting you want to achieve your plot and character development goals.

Comment: Ironically, a nuclear war will leave the cities as open junkyards to be looted at one's pleasure, so the problem is already solved. A junkyard can be useful if you're looting for certain components, but it is no place to make a living, since its grounds were already terribly polluted before the war. But it would be a treasure trove to be defended.

Comment: The amount of toxic chemicals leached into the environment involved with batteries, leaded glass etc,. would probably make it a bad idea unless it was adjacent to something a lot healthier to grow crops on. Metals found in junkyards are not going to be scarce in an apocalypse. In fact they would be plentiful and better quality elsewhere. Junkyard tools would save some scavenging but not much else. Better off at a car factory or similar if thats what you're after. Then you would have unmoulded pristine sheet metal etc,.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE, John!  When you have a moment, please take our [tour] and visit our [help] to learn mor about us.  We can get your question off hold with some repairs.  (1) Please clarify what you mean by "junkyard."  We have participants around the world and the word means different things to different people.  (2) StackExchange sites are not discussion forums.  You can't ask for an [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130/catalog-of-question-types/6139#6139), but you can ask for...

Comment: a [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6130/catalog-of-question-types/6138#6138).  You may not believe it, but asking "what are the pros and cons of living in a junkyard" is asking for a finite list of things, while "would a junkyard be a good place to build a city?" is asking for an infinite list of things.  Please try to be as specific as possible with your questions.  The more specific you are, the less subjective the answers, and the more on-topic it becomes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Filling the basic needs is the first step. Basic needs for survival are as follows:

> Food
>
> ### Water
>
> Shelter

One of these is easy to answer. In a junkyard, there would be plenty of scrap metal and spare parts to build shelters.

Food and water are the major variables here and these would change drastically from situation to situation based on things such as pollution and location.

I'll start with water. If, for example, the junkyard is near a river, water is readily available. If the river is clean water, it should easily sustain a civilization there. If the river is not clean, the civilization could employ distillation techniques, but these would require a significant amount of time and effort. So much so that some members of the civilization might even just be "the water cleaning guy". This would also either require fuel for a fire or some way to harness solar power and focus it into a water container.
On the other hand, if the junkyard is not near a river or similar body of water, citizens would need to either transport water from a nearby source or collect rainwater. The former could be achieved through aqueducts (e.g. Rome) or would need dedicated water carriers; the latter could be achieved through a large number of open containers, but may still need to be cleaned.

Let's move on to food. Agriculture is the obvious first choice, but this would also mean that you need at least some amount of water. If the city relies on rainwater collection, then the climate is probably not too arid to grow food. Easy sources of food would include sweet potatoes, which a human could survive by eating almost exclusively (needing only higher calcium, zinc, and riboflavin), and kale, which leads to another problem: Thallium poisoning. Kale, while ridiculously high in vitamins (100 grams of kale contains 200% of your daily Vitamin C needs, 300% of your Vitamin A needs, and 1000% of your needs for Vitamin K1). Kale also may inhibit iodine absorption which may lead to hypothyroidism. The other solution would be to raise animals, but this requires a large amount of land.

An easy solution, assuming water and land requirements are met, would be to grow sweet potatoes and raise cattle for both dairy and meat. What the sweet potatoes lack in zinc, the beef can provide, what they lack in calcium, the dairy cows could provide in the form of cheese and milk, and what they lack in riboflavin, the beef liver can provide.

As for becoming a mecca, that really has nothing to do with the question at all.

TL;DR: Maybe. It's as feasible as any other location.